# Nested Average(Small(offset)) in Sheets isn't producing correct result

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, nested-function

I want to calculate the average of the smallest 20 numbers in a range (using offset), then multiply it by 0.96 using a Google sheet.

This is the formula we have:

```
=AVERAGE(SMALL(OFFSET(B13,2,0,20),{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10}))*0.96
```

(See below for pictures)

The function should output 24, but instead it's outputting 14. 
I think it has something to do with the range of numbers for 'n' in the nested 'small' function, but for the life of me I can't figure out what it is. I've linked some pictures:

[image: Set of numbers for the offset formula.]
[image: Entire google sheet]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since the data in your image only has 20 rows, i am assuming you mean to calculate average of smallest 10 numbers from the 20 rows. Try this formula

```
=AVERAGE(SMALL(OFFSET(B13,0,0,20,1),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}))
```

Please note the the formula should be entered as an array i,.e. type the formula and press `Ctrl + shift + enter`